# Problema com go to definition

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estou com um problema que surgiu há poucos dias. Venho trabalhando em um projeto há 3 anos. De uns 10 dias para cá, ao executar o comando GO TO DEFINITION sobre um determinado codigo fonte, está sendo exibido para mim um documento com metadados ao invés do codigo fonte. Alguem sabe o que pode ter causado este comportamento?

Comment: Olá, poderia exibir o trecho do código referênte ao problema?

Comment: acho que você está tentando ver a definição de algo não está no seu projeto, mas sim proveniente de uma referência externa.

Comment: O que estou tentando ver é meu. Meu projeto possui 4 camadas (View, Contextos, BLL e Dao). Estou tentando ver projetos da BLL. Esse é um trecho o codigo:  PreferenciaTerminal pref = PreferenciasTerminalBLL.retornaPreferenciasTerminal(); Se eu executar CTRL + Click spbre "retornaPreferenciasTerminal() ocorre o problema mencionado.